# How to resolve graph2vec error invalid literal for int()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, networkx

I am trying to run [graph2vec](https://github.com/benedekrozemberczki/graph2vec) on some small networks I have created.  It gets through the feature extraction stage OK but when it starts optimization it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "src/graph2vec.py", line 129, in <module> main(args)
   File "src/graph2vec.py", line 125, in main save_embedding(args.output_path, model, graphs, args.dimensions)
   File "src/graph2vec.py", line 98, in save_embedding out.append([int(identifier)] + list(model.docvecs["g_"+identifier]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dataset\\0'
```

Research tells me this error happens when an integer is expected but some other data type is provided.  It looks like maybe it's trying to pass dataset\0 for identifier when it should be passing just 0?

I set up the directory structure as specified in the docs:

```
graph2vec
    dataset
       [contains many json data files]
    features
    src
        graph2vec.py
        param_parser.py
```

And am running `python src/graph2vec.py` from the top graph2vec directory.  Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that the normal graph2vec library linked above assumes a Linux installation, and there is a [karateclub](https://github.com/benedekrozemberczki/karateclub) implementation that works for Windows.  The issue was it was choking on the backslashes.